# Angular material mat option selected value highlight

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to highlight background colour of the selected value which is clicked. I was going through this example
Here it is highlighting multiple select value. I want to highlight only the selected value when click to choose an option.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-selection-color-change?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Area 3 is initially selected. The displayed array below updates as options are selected/deselected.
</p>
<div>
  Selected: {{ selectedOptions | json }}
</div>

<mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" [value]="tta.name">
      {{tta.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

app.css

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

mat-list-option {
  margin: 10px;
}

mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: By what criteria you want to highlight only one?

Comment: Whenever I am clicking an option.The selected value should be highlighted

Comment: Check out my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-selection-color-change-wkj3ci) to see how to highlight only the last selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mat-selection-list is not suitable for single value selection but still, if you want to you can try something like this.

```
mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

you have to clear your list on every selection
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3pfu2-kylx8v

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:  Based on current mat-selection-list options: https://material.angular.io/components/list/api

declaring *[multiple]="false"* and addressing *.mat-list-single-selected-option* style this will highlight the currently selected mat-list-option

```
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
  <mat-list-option>1</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option>2</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option>3</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

```
.mat-list-item.mat-list-single-selected-option {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```